# How to pass additional information in source() in R

Tags: r

I have a R file. I want to use it as a source and pass additional information so I can get the new result each time.

I tried few things but I could not figure so I was wondering if anyone knows how to do that.
An example of R file I saved

```
## saved as TrySo.R

x=c(3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,45,34,2,2,1,1,1)
y=c("a","a","b","a","b","b","c","c","a","b","c","a","a","c","b")

subTothis="a"

XY=data.frame(x,y)

A=dplyr::filter(XY,y==subTothis)

## 

L=NULL
for(i in 1:dim(A)[1])
{
  L[i]=A$x[i]^2+3
}

L
```

I want to change `subTothis="a"` to `"b"` so on.

```
C=source("C:/Users/Rcode/TrySo.R")
```

Comment: Rather than using `source()` to run code chunks, it would be easier if you just defined proper functions in your sourced file and then call those functions with whatever parameters you want.

Comment: That's true but then I have to put the whole function in R file. When I have 6 of these type of R file. It makes it hard to track down.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that comment. When you `source()` an R file, R just runs each line as if you typed it in. If you have a line that says `subTothis="a"`, it will run that code. It can't change the hard coded value. You'd need to replace it with something you can change. I guess you could say `subTothis <- if(exists("subTothis")) subTothis else "a"` and then you could set the variable in your containing script. But that's really messy. A function is a better long term solution.

Answer (score -1):

We could create a properties file (`ApplicationProp.INI`) and parse the info from that file.  The contents of the file can be

```
# // ConfigParser reads the properties from each section
[source-this]
subTothis = a
```

Whenever, we want to change anything, just change this file instead of the R script and the values passed here will get updated

---

In the original script `TrySo.R`

```
library(ConfigParser)
props <- ConfigParser$new()
applicationpropfilepath <- "C:/Users/Rcode/ApplicationProp.INI"
props <- props$read(applicationpropfilepath)$data

...
subTothis = props[["source-this"]][["subToThis"]]
...
```

Comment: Should I put "library(ConfigParser)
props <- ConfigParser$new()
props <- props$read(applicationpropfilepath)$data" in TrySo.R file ? and what is "applicationpropfilepath" ?

Comment: @iHermes It is the path where the file is created.  It can be in the same folder where your script R is i.e. `"C:/Users/Rcode/ApplicationProp.INI"`

Comment: Yes, the R script will include that library and theextraction from that properties file

Comment: @iHermes The advantage of creating a file like that would be to pass any variables by creating sections or adding new elements to each section

Comment: @iHermes Not sure if you are getting any errors as these works very well for me

Comment: Yes I am getting "the file is not in the directory " for `C:/Users/Rcode/ApplicationProp.INI`

Comment: @iHermes If you created the file `Applicationprop.INI` with those contents and it is the correct path, it should work (as I tested this already)

Comment: I did not create anything. I guess that's the problem. How to create that file ?

Comment: @iHermes You can create a file in R studio (or in any other editor) and save the contents as `Applicationprop.INI`